# How to calculate difference between two points in some values?

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I have 5 values which are `-2, -1, 0, 1, 2`. I want to calculate difference between two variables which contains the values from these given values.

Suppose I have two variables `x` and `y`. Suppose following cases :

`x = 0, y = 0` i.e. `(x == y)` then return value should be `2`.

`x = 1, y = -1` or vice versa  then the return value should be `0`.

`x = -2, y = 2` or vice versa then the return value should be `-2`.

I have to use this formula in a program.

Comment: Is the case `x = 1, y = 2` possible?

Comment: yes, return value should be 1 in that case too. Because distance between points is 1.

Comment: What is the reasoning of the results ? Why is `x = -2, y = 2` or vice versa then the return value should be `-2` ?

Comment: Because of the distance between points. Actually I solved this and posting as answer.

Comment: what do you mean by difference between two variables?

Comment: Please check my answer then you will get to know. I need this in my coding. I am a web developer actually not a mathematician. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this by using following formula :

$$ d(x,y) = 2 - |x - y| $$

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @quid The description is in question itself. Please let me know if there is anything that is not understandable.

Comment: Sorry. This was an autogenerated comment. I did not get you meant this as a self-answer. Sorry, again.